# Java MouseClick Listener not working

Tags: java, events, awt, listener, mouselistener

So I'm working on a deal or no deal java game essentially, and right now I'm trying to have the image icon disappear where the user clicked. So I have an 6 by 6 array of 'metal briefcase' (casesArray) image icons, but regardless of where the user clicks, only the image icon in the top left disappears. I'm guessing this is just a logic mistake on my part, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong...

```
class MouseClickListener implements MouseListener
    {
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getX() <= 133)row=0;
            else if (event.getX() <= 267 && event.getX()>133)row=1;
            else if (event.getX() <= 400 && event.getX()>267)row=2;
            else if (event.getX() <= 533 && event.getX()>400)row=3;
            else if (event.getX() <= 667 && event.getX()>533)row=4;
            else if (event.getX() <= 800 && event.getX()>667)row=5;
             if (event.getY() <= 100)column=0;
            else if (event.getY() <= 200 && event.getY() > 100)column=1;
            else if (event.getY() <= 300 && event.getY() > 200)column=2;
            else if (event.getY() <= 400 && event.getY() > 300)column=3;
            else if (event.getY() <= 500 && event.getY() > 400)column=4;
            else if (event.getY() <= 600 && event.getY() > 500)column=5;

            casesArray[row][column].setIcon(null);
            repaint();
        }
    .
    .
    .
    .
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            casesArray[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseClickListener());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `getX()`/ `getY()` return coordinates **relative to each component**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MouseEvent`s are contextual to the component that raised them.  That is, the x/y point of the event is automatically converted to the coordinate space of the component that the event occurred on.

So, if a component exists at 100x100 within it's parent, when you click on it, the mouse event will be converted so coordinates are 0x0, representing the top level corner of the component that was clicked.

Instead of using a series of `if` statements, try actually referencing the component directly...

```
class MouseClickListener implements MouseListener
{
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event)
    {
        Component comp = event.getComponent();
        if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
            ((JLabel)comp).setIcon(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated with additional example**

`MouseEvent#getSource` returns a reference to the object that created the event...

```
class MouseClickListener implements MouseListener
{
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event)
    {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        for (int x = 0; x < casesArray.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < casesArray[x].length; y++) {
                if (casesArray[x][y] == source) {
                    casesArray[x][y].setIcon(null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A safer solution would be to continue using `getComponent` as the source of the event could potentially be different to the component that the event occurred on...

```
class MouseClickListener implements MouseListener
{
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event)
    {
        Component source = event.getComponent();
        for (int x = 0; x < casesArray.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < casesArray[x].length; y++) {
                if (casesArray[x][y] == source) {
                    casesArray[x][y].setIcon(null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Working example

[image]

This basically loads a bunch of images from a folder and displays them in a 6x6 grid.  Click on any image will set it's corresponding label's icon to `null`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ClickTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClickTest();
    }

    public ClickTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel[][] casesArray;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 6));

            File[] files = new File("/path/to/lots/of/images").listFiles();

            MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                    Object source = event.getSource();
                    for (int x = 0; x < casesArray.length; x++) {
                        for (int y = 0; y < casesArray[x].length; y++) {
                            if (casesArray[x][y] == source) {
                                casesArray[x][y].setIcon(null);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            casesArray = new JLabel[6][6];
            int index = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
                    JLabel label = new JLabel();
                    try {
                        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(files[index++])));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    label.addMouseListener(listener);
                    casesArray[x][y] = label;
                    add(casesArray[x][y]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately my teacher has not taught us any of that and I need to stay within the bounds of his lesson so that's why I was trying to use the if statements with the source of the click

Comment: +1,  @user2228503 use a single MouseListener. You don't need to create 36 MouseListeners.

Comment: @user2228503 Then you are going to lose.  The only thing you can do is either check the `event.getSource()` against the list of `casesArray` directly (ie `caseArray[x][y] == event.getSource()` within a compound loop OR you can take the easy way and use what the API is providing you...

Comment: doesn't the case array contain index values inside the []'s whereas the getSource returns x and y coordinates. I'm not questioning your answer, I just don't understand how it would work exactly...

Comment: `MouseEvent#getSource` returns a reference to the object that created the event. Check update

Comment: Thanks for updating you're answer. I did try to use you're code directly, but now nothing happens when I click any of the buttons...

Comment: Have you tried adding a `repaint` in after setting the icon to `null`?  May even try `revalidate`?

Comment: -1 (cancelling the +1), for the "working example". There is no need to loop through the arrays. You already have the source button. The setIcon() method invokes revalidate()/repaint(), as do other methods that change a property of a Swing component. It is more likely the OP's code is wrong then Swing not working properly. Ops, I only meant to cancel my upvote, but it looks like I gave a downvote by mistake.

Comment: @camickr I agree, but the OP want's it that way, besides, the example demonstrates that the concept works and there is something else wrong with their code.

Answer (score 1):

> but regardless of where the user clicks, only the image icon in the top left disappears

Well you are adding a MouseListener to each of the components. Therefore the mouse point will be relative to each JLabel. So therefore only the first label has accurate mouse points.

If you want to use if/else logic then you should only add a single MouseListener to the parent JPanel that contains the 36 labels. Then the mouse point is relative to the panel and you can use math to determine which label is at a specific location on the panel assuming you know the size of each label.

The better solution is to create a single listener, but add the listener to each of the labels. Then you just use the getSource() method as has been mentioned by MadProgrammer. You teacher should be teaching you how to use write generic listeners that can be used by multiple components. Any time you see if/else logic you know you have a bad design.

Comment: doesn't the getSource method return an x,y location? I don't understand how that would work in the array to choose the right 'case'

Comment: I though you were usig getX() and getY() to get the location. Why would you think the getSource() method also does that? What does the API say for the getSource() method? What does the array have to do with anything? MadProgrammer gave you working code. His suggestion to use the getComponent() method is better since you don't have to cast the "source" object to a "component". There is no need to reference the array with his suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Netbeans Ide Design mode to gen code Events and copy code that way

Ex: Jlabel Event Mouse Click:

1. Add Mouse Listener
   `lboKH.addMouseListener(lb_Mouse_Click_Event);`
2. Declare event

`private MouseListener lb_Mouse_Click_Event = new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {`

```
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getRootPane(), "a");
    }
};
```